# Merging Domain Ontologies

Tags: jena, ontology, owl

I have worked and developed two different domain ontologies. But now i like to merge these two ontologies as my application requirement has been changed and requires knowledge of both ontologies. What are merging techniques and how can i do it with ontology framework i.e jena, OWL-API etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your ontologies are following the [OWL 2 EL](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-profiles/#OWL_2_EL) profile you can do it with [Brain](https://github.com/loopasam/Brain):

```
Brain brain = new Brain();
brain.learn("path/to/first_ontology.owl");
brain.learn("path/to/second_ontology.owl");
//Do your logic here, like queries, etc...
brain.save("path/to/merged_ontologies.owl");
```

Entities with identical IRIs will be automatically merged.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have two ontologies: modelA and modelB, if you are using Jena, you can do the following thing to merge them:

```
modelA.add(modelB);
```

or

```
modelB.add(modelA);
```